# Tree structure in sql in Oracle.How to show tree,child nodes and parent nodes in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, connect-by

I would like to show a tree structure in SQL with child nodes and parent nodes.
I have a table like:

```
Employee
-------------
ID (int)
FirstName (varchar)
LastName (varchar)
ParentID (int)
Job (varchar)
```

which represents an employee. **ParentID** represent the manager of the employee has. I would like to have this table only with this structure.

1. I would like to show the whole tree structure.
2. I would like to show only the children nodes
3. I would like to show only the parent nodes

[SampleDataImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCqdM.png)

Comment: Please add some sample data, desired result and what you tried so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect-by+oracle or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical-data+oracle or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+recursive-query

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I edit the post and added a sample data image. Also I would like to show the whole tree structure with an sql query and on another query I would like to show only the children nodes and on a third query I would like to show only what are parent nodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL creating different levels of data from a single table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085015/oracle-sql-creating-different-levels-of-data-from-a-single-table)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the time to search for similar questions on SO before asking a new one - there are literally *tons* of questions on SO about Oracle and hierarchical data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Query - The whole tree structure**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee
START WITH ParentID IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ParentID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY LastName, FirstName, ID;
```

**Query - The children of a given employee**:

You do not need a hierarchical query for this.
*(The parent is given by the bind variable `:parent_id`)*

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee
WHERE  ParentID = :parent_id
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, ID;
```

**Query - The descendants of a given employee**:

The same query as for the whole tree but with a different start point
*(The parent is given by the bind variable `:parent_id`)*

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee
START WITH ParentID = :parent_id
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ParentID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY LastName, FirstName, ID;
```

**Query - The employee and their ancestors**:

Similar to the previous query but with the `CONNECT BY` reversed and you won't need to order the siblings as there will only be one immediate manager per employee.
*(The employee is given by the bind variable `:employee_id`)*

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee
START WITH ID = :employee_id
CONNECT BY PRIOR ParentID = ID;
```

**Query - The employee's manager**:

Identical to the previous query but with a filter `LEVEL = 2` to just get the immediate parent row.
*(The employee is given by the bind variable `:employee_id`)*

```
SELECT e.*
FROM   Employee e
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
START WITH ID = :employee_id
CONNECT BY PRIOR ParentID = ID;
```